# Center align image action in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add your photo", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

var image = UIImage(named: "avatar.png")

image = image?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, view.frame.width/2 - (image?.size.width)!/2, 0, 0))

let imageAction = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: nil)

imageAction.setValue(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")

alert.addAction(imageAction)
```

By default, the icon is being left aligned and I tried to center align it by using UIEdgeInset (line 3 above). Considering the top left corner being the origin (0,0), I tried to position the image at the center along the horizontal axis with the left inset value as in the code but the image is obtained as below. So I know this is not correct. I can manage to get it in the center by trial and error. But I would like to come up with a proper way to center align it. What would be the right way to achieve this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use `forKey: "image"`, because is a [private api](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements).

If you want to add an image inside an alert controller, you might try with `NSLayoutConstraint`, doing so:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add your photo", message: "\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Upload", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add later", style: .default, handler: nil))
let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "avatar"))
alert.view.addSubview(image)
image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
alert.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: alert.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
alert.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: alert.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
alert.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64.0))
alert.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64.0))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

result is:

[image]

Comment: I'm generating the alert on viewDidAppear(). When I make this viewcontroller the initial one, your code is working fine. But when i start over from my beginning screen (with navigation controller), the image gets positioned around the bottom. Not sure about this issue, however I fixed this by delaying the alert generation by few seconds. I have accepted your solution, thank you. Any thoughts regarding the new issue?

Comment: @Sujal I made a project based on your observation, you may find it here: https://github.com/mugx/testalert but I am not able to reproduce such glitch, might you double check?

Comment: I've a series of VC: VC1->VC2->VC3->VC4 all embedded in a navigation controller.VC4 is the one in which the alert is shown. When I make either of those VCs the initial view controller, its working fine. But when i make the navigation controller initial controller, the image gets mispositioned. So I even tried a separate project like your github project and also checked the effect of adding navigation. But in either cases (with/ without nav), no issue is found. I dont know what is causing like this in my app.

Comment: Its not improving, its giving the same result. Printing the CGPoint using frame and bound shows the same value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162443/discussion-between-andrea-mugnaini-and-sujal).

Comment: How can I adjust the alert size for larger image (say an image in landscape/ portrait mode)?

Comment: add/remove `\n` inside the `message: "\n\n\n"`

Comment: I had already tried adding \n. The problem is related to landscape images where the image width exceeds the width of the alert dialog.

Comment: @Sujal Ok, no worry. I edited the answer adding constraints for width and height (in the example 64.0). Let me now if that fix your problem.

Comment: I can now change those constraints as per my image to show in the alert dialog. Thank you :)

Comment: @Sujal Glad you found it useful. Feel free to up-vote :)

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini I set constraints for width = 223, height = 140 and the image overlapped my uialertviewcontroller. =.=. This solution may not apply for large size images.

Answer (score 1):

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unfollow John Doe?", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let imageAction = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let image = UIImage(named: "user_img_a")
        let alertViewPadding: CGFloat = 65.0 //Adjust this as per your need
        let left = -alert.view.frame.size.width / 2 + image!.size.width/2 + 20
       // let left = alert.view.frame.size.width/2 - image!.size.width/2
        let centeredTopoImage = image?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, left, 0, 0)).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageAction.setValue(centeredTopoImage, forKey: "image")


        let  deleteButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Unfollow", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Delete button tapped")
            self.arrLikes[sender.tag]=0

            self.tblList.reloadData()
        })

        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Cancel button tapped")

        })

        alert.addAction(imageAction)
        alert.addAction(deleteButton)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Add some explanation